# javascript namespacing in sharepoint 2010 master page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, namespaces

I have made an custom master page in a Sharepoint Foundation site, and i would to insert custom javascript using namespacing.
this is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var CapMossJs = {
         setCurrentMonthInCombo: function () {
             //var objComboMesi = getField('select', 'Mese');   
             var datCurrent = new Date();
             var intCurrMonth = datCurrent.getMonth();
            window.alert(intCurrMonth);
        },

         hideUtenteSrcurlTemplatelink: function() {
         }
     }      
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $().ready(function () {
         CapMossJs.setCurrentMonthInCombo();
     });
 </script>
```

that i have inserted in the master page after the lines

```
 id="onetidPageTitleAreaFrameScript"
 if (document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame") != null)   {
   document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame").className="ms-areaseparator";
```

after line 491 in practice.
In a normal page made with visual studio 2010 this code works, instead in the master page i have an error from jquery that the property or method is not supported from object: could someone explain why ? without namespacing there are no problems.

Comment: you should provide some more code where you actually put the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a script tag inside another script tag, and none of the code that you add should be inside that `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The same code without namespacing works without problems, the two lines relative to the "if" are only a reference of the place in code , if you open with SharePoint Designer a custom form it will be clear: in every case my scripts tags are after line 491 , where there is already another script tag.